# Subscribe reactive form value

Tags: angular

how to subscribe entire form value as an object. There is a way to do it on value changes, but I need it on function.

Code for subscribing value on value change

```
this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data)));
```

But how to do it normally..

This is my reactive form code

```
  this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
            systemId: ['', Validators.required],
            user: ['', Validators.required],
            pwd: ['', Validators.required]  
        });
```

Comment: *"But how to do it normally.."*. you really need to clarify question.

Comment: I need to pass entire form values to other component, above I have mentioned only 3 controls but there are more, so, rather than passing individual value, it will be easy if I`m able to send as an object

Comment: i'm not sure if i understand your question properly but you can try this                  let value=this.form.getRawValue();

Answer (score 1):

You can access the form value at anytime/anyfunction with: `this.form.value`

Comment: Thanks that really helped